# Solr sunspot pdf indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, solr

I am following this tutorial to index pdf document to solr 
https://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/
And my model is

```
class Manual < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :pdf_document, PdfUploader
    before_save :update_upload_attributes

    # Sunspot indexing configuration
  searchable do
    # Regular fields that I want indexed
    text :name

    # For Sunspot Cell. The 'attachment' directive instructs
    # Cell how to get the binary data. My understanding is that
    # this *must* end in _attachment
    attachment :pdf_document
  end
    private
        def update_upload_attributes
        if pdf_document.present? && pdf_document_changed?
          self.content_type = pdf_document.file.content_type
          self.file_size = pdf_document.file.size
          self.file_name = File.basename(pdf_document.url)
        end
      end
end
```

But when I try to reindex I get the following error

```
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...
[####################################] [2/2] [100.00%] [00:00] [00:00] [54.90/s]
```

And when I try to submit the form I get following error

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error: {'error'=>{'msg'=>'java.lang.AbstractMethodError','trace'=>'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it's old question, but for someone from google search, like me, it's may help save couple hours -

In question's link to [blog](https://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/) - pretty good cookbook-style article, but gems using there are outdated and not compatible with current version of sunspot gem.

Check please updated gem [sunspot_cell](https://github.com/brovikov/sunspot_cell). It compatible with Sunspot gem >= 2.2.5 . Actually, it's an updated mirror of dead version of sunspot_cell gem.